# I have a GSM breakout board for my Arduino. Is triangulation possible?

Tags: arduino, gsm, triangulation, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I want to be able to get coordinates of where i am using my arduino and GSM breakout board. is it possible, if so how?

Comment: belongs to http://arduino.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can check if your module accept some `ATComands` and follow this instructable:
[LINK](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-a-Mobile-Cellular-Location-Logger-with/step3/The-AT-Commands/)

Using the commands:

```
AT+CMGF=1
AT+CGATT=1
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","your apn here"
AT+SAPBR=1,1
AT+CIPGSMLOC=1,1
```